# Sorting alphabetically applied coupons in WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, cart, coupon

For some reasons I need to apply coupons to an order in a correct sequence - alphabetic (A-B-C). User is able to add coupons a various ways (B-A-C, C-A-B etc or even C-A). So I'd like to sort added coupons and add these to the order in correct way.

I'm trying to fix but with no luck:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_applied_coupon', 'sort_coupon' );
if (!function_exists('sort_coupon') ) {

    function sort_coupon() {
        global $woocommerce;
        $cart_coupons = WC()->cart->get_applied_coupons();
        sort($cart_coupons);
        WC()->cart->remove_coupons();
        foreach ( $cart_coupons as $code ) {
            WC()->cart->add_discount( $code );
        }
        WC()->cart->calculate_totals();
    }
}
```

How can I make it work?

Answer (score 0):

As **`woocommerce_applied_coupon`** hook is already located in **`WC_Cart add_discount()`** method, then you can't use it as it makes a kind of loop…

Instead you should hook in your function in **`woocommerce_cart_coupon`** action hook this way:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_cart_coupon', 'custom_sort_coupons' );
function custom_sort_coupons() {

    if ( is_admin() && ! defined( 'DOING_AJAX' ) )
        return;

    $applied_coupons = WC()->cart->get_applied_coupons();
    WC()->cart->remove_coupons();

    sort($applied_coupons);

    foreach ( $applied_coupons as $coupon_code ) {
        WC()->cart->add_discount( $coupon_code );
        wc_clear_notices(); // Avoid repetitive notices
    }
    WC()->cart->calculate_totals();
}
```

Code goes in any php file of your active child theme (or theme) or also in any plugin php file.

> Now this is working. I have add **`wc_clear_notices()`** in the last loop to avoid repetitive notices

Comment: Thank you for your reply. You are right - I hung my server already. Using `woocommerce_cart_coupon` `instead woocommerce_applied_coupon` works fine but only if I push Refresh basket button. If user push Checkout then we go to checkout without sorting.

Comment: @Fasolechka As ajax is enabled on my test server on cart and checkout pages, I don't have this problem … I am using for testing the classic WooCommerce Storefront theme... Everything is updated without refreshing on mine.